# I have to call api for getting 2000 items, it is freezing the app, i have to show this data in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to call api for getting 2000 items, it is freezing the app, i have to show this data in `tableview`.

I'm using  `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)`

But it not working, after getting complete data then it is showing in table view.

Please give right suggestion for this which is best way.

Comment: do you know exactly where the "freezing" happens? is it converting the data into json? is it converting that json into objects? -- because `UITableView` is smart enough to only create as much cells as you can fit on the page. Ultimately the solution is to paginate this call, but if that is not possible you are back to working out exactly what is taking so long and trying to work that out or workaround that. Also post actual code; It is very hard to work out potential problems with your implementation without it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling 2000 items at a time is not a good thing. You can use paging technology to collect data.

Comment: How to use paging technology for the same.  We dont want to click any item.

Comment: First you get 200 data then on success you can call 200 data again. This way you can solve the issue.

Comment: not sure, this will work because application will freeze when we are asking for 200 records as well. suppose server is slow

Comment: decrease the time out. put it at 10 sec  and if data is not received kill the thread.

Comment: @vats If the server is slow as he mentioned, you will never get data. So why sending a request?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I meant time out.

Comment: @vats I know, you wrote it. But if the server is that slow that he does not respond in time with the actual time out, it would not respond using a decreased time out. Therefore he will never get data, if he decreases the time out.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this way helps you..Using pagination solves this.
Every time you can load only 50 records at a time form server..When user scrolls , call your server hit to load next 50 records and append to your global array:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

for (UITableviewcell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self.tableView numberOfItemsInSection:0] - 1;
    NSInteger firstRowIndex = [self.tableView numberOfItemsInSection:0] - responseJson.count ;


    if(indexPath.row ==lastRowIndex ){

                strPageNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)responseJson.count];
               //Send this page count to server and retrieve next 50 records

                NSLog(@"  strPageNo count  index path %@",strPageNo);
                [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourMethodToRetriveRecords) withObject:nil];



          }
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).Its easy to use and its also well optimized library.Calls are asynchronous that will not hang your app.
For paging using [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) library.
Both libraries will save your time and performance.